# JSP/Spring MVC - How to populate list dynamically with elements added to model (javascript/jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring-mvc, jsp, jstl

First my apologies if the question is not clear enough. I will edit it if convenient to see if this can help someone else in the future.

I have a form in a JSP binded to a Spring MVC model which would retrieve the information entered by the user.
The thing is that I will allow multiple submissions/entries that are passed as a list (movies) in the example below. Each time the user clicks Add, the fields are cloned to allow a new entry (and previous fields are hidden/removed). Finally, when clicking Submit, the form is posted to the controller to persist the data.

All that is working fine. What I want to achieve is to create a list that to dynamically show all entries that are being added every time the user hits Add.

This is what I have for the list (with only one field for simplicity here)

```
<form:form id="myForm" method="post" modelAttribute="cinema" action="submitMovies">
    <!-- List to be filled dynamically with elements from my model (now empty) ->
     <div id="files" class="list-section collapse in">
        <div class="item-list-container" id="groupedList">
            <div class="labels">
                <div class="item">Title</div>
            </div>
            <div class="grey-background">
                <c:forEach items="movies" var="movie" varStatus="loop" >
                    <div class="itemContainer">
                        <div class="subGroup ">
                            <div class="item " id="">Want to display names entered in form here i.e fourth row would show content of movies[3].movieName</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </c:forEach>
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
```

(Not really required for my problem but imagine my model is a class Cinema with a List movies;
And Movie.class would have a String movieName attribute.)

I have that forEach but the list doesn't add a row after clicking Add. So obviously this is not refreshing its content.

Adding the rest of the form below with one field and Add button.
The Add button just clone what is in the Clone Item div and change the id of the fields. For example:
`<form:input id="movieName${loop.index}" path="movies[${loop.index}].movieName"`  initially is id="movieName0" binded to movies[0].movieName and after Add a new element gets created with movieName1 binded to movies[1].movieName

**Again, this is working fine.** The only thing I'm looking for is for a way that when I click Add and elements are created (movieName1 binded to movies[1].movieName) to dynamically display in that list/table a new row with the information that was previously in the form (movieName0 binded to movies[0].movieName)

````
    <!-- List to be filled dynamically with elements from my model (now empty) ->
     <div id="files" class="list-section collapse in">
        <div class="item-list-container" id="groupedList">
            <div class="labels">
                <div class="item">Title</div>
            </div>
            <div class="grey-background">
                <c:forEach items="movies" var="movie" varStatus="loop" >
                    <div class="itemContainer">
                        <div class="subGroup ">
                            <div class="item " id="">Want to display names entered in form here</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </c:forEach>
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>

     <!-- Start Clone Item -->
     <div class="cloneList" data-count="${movies.size() + 0}">
     <c:forEach items="movies" var="movie" varStatus="loop" begin="0" >
     <!-- Cloned item -->
        <div class="cloneItem" id="innerItem${loop.index}">
            <div id="movieNameField${loop.index}" class="form-group">
                 <label for="movieName${loop.index}">NAME</label>
                 <div class="status-container">
                    <form:input id="movieName${loop.index}" path="movies[${loop.index}].movieName" maxlength="35" class="form-control"/>
                 </div>
                 <form:errors path="movies[${loop.index}].movieName" cssClass="errorShow" element="div"/>
            </div>
        </div>
     </c:forEach>
     </div>
     <!-- End Clone -->

     <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <a class="btn btn-primary" href="javascript:void(0)" id="addMovie" onclick="addMovie()"><spring:message code="button.add" /></a><br>
        </div>
     </div>

     <!-- More code to submit form etc -->
</form:form>```


**EDIT:** addMovie() content added as requested.
````

```
function addMovie() {

var target = $('.cloneList');

//Keep track of number of movies
var listCount = $('.cloneList').attr("data-count");

var innerItem = $('div[id^="innerItem"]:last');

var num = parseInt(innerItem.prop("id").match(/\d+/g), 10) + 1;
$('.cloneList').attr("data-count", num);

var clone = innerItem.clone().prop('id', 'innerItem' + num).find("input:text").val("").end();

clone.find('#movieName' + listCount).attr("name","movies[" + num + "].movieName").attr("id","movieNameField" + num).text("");
clone.find('#movieNameField' + listCount).attr("id","movieNameField" + num).text("");
```

target.append(clone);

Comment: So you need whatever user enter in the input field while cloning should also show `<div class="item " id=""></div>` here ? Can you post your `addMovie()` code as well?

Comment: Yes. I guess that an option would be to have the table also cloning a row and show same values. But I would rather find a way to display the actual content of the binding i.e movies[2].movieName.   I'll edit with the content of addMovie()

Comment: Also ,you need to show values in inputbox or just text i.e : `movies1`,`movies2` .etc?

Comment: Values, of course

Comment: Hi ,did you tried below code ? does that works for you ?

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through `values` of input and then add those values to the div where you need to show names .In below code i have use `<ul></ul>` tags to show list inside div but ,here you can add input field with same name which you are generating so that it will bind to the required values .

I have done some changes in your jquery code because previously it was not appending inputs correctly .So , i have corrected that and now each new row will be appended inside `cloneItem` .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
function addMovie() {
  var values = ""; //declare this
  //Keep track of number of movies
  var listCount = $('.cloneList').attr("data-count");
  var innerItem = $('div[id^="innerItem"]:last');
  var num = parseInt(innerItem.prop("id").match(/\d+/g), 10) + 1;
  $('.cloneList').attr("data-count", num);

  var clone = innerItem.clone().prop('id', 'innerItem' + num).find("input:text").val("").end();
  //added this to show label attr correct value
  clone.find("label").attr("for", "movieNameField" + num)
  clone.find('#movieName' + listCount).attr("name", "movies[" + num + "].movieName").attr("id", "movieNameField" + num).attr('path', "movies[" + num + "].movieName").text("");
  clone.find('#movieNameField' + listCount).attr("id", "movieNameField" + num);

  clone.insertAfter("div.cloneItem:last")
  values = "<ul>"
  //loop through all inputs
  $(".cloneItem").find("input.values").each(function() {
    //check if values ! =null
    if ($(this).val() != "") {
      //append
      values += "<li>" + $(this).val() + " </li>"
    }
  })
  values += "</ul>"
  //add values to div
  $("#displays").html(values)
}
```

```css
li {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="files" class="list-section collapse in">
  <div class="item-list-container" id="groupedList">
    <div class="labels">
      <div class="item">Title</div>
    </div>
    <div class="grey-background">
      <div class="itemContainer">
        <div class="subGroup">
          <!--added id-->
          <div class="item " id="displays">Want to display names entered in form here</div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Start Clone Item -->
<div class="cloneList" data-count="1">
  <!-- Cloned item -->
  <div class="cloneItem" id="innerItem1">
    <div id="movieNameField1" class="form-group">
      <label for="movieName1">NAME</label>
      <div class="status-container">
        <!--added extra class=values-->
        <input id="movieName1" path="movies[1].movieName" maxlength="35" value="Movies1" class="form-control values" />
      </div>
      <form:errors path="movies[1].movieName" cssClass="errorShow" element="div" />
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
<!-- End Clone -->

<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="javascript:void(0)" id="addMovie" onclick="addMovie()">
     Add
    </a><br>
  </div>
</div>
```